# Google test and operator<< overload for STL types

Tags: c++, googletest

Why following code produces compilation error?

```
#include <iostream>
#include "gtest/gtest.h"
#include <utility>

namespace A {
    //overloading operator << for std::pair
    template<typename T1, typename T2>
    std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const std::pair<T1, T2>& p) {
        return os << "pair:{" << p.first << ", " << p.second << "}";
    }

    struct C {
        int x;
    };
    std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const C& c) {
        return os << c.x;
    }

    TEST(TestA, testA) {
        std::pair<C, C> pair1;
        std::pair<int, int> pair2;

        EXPECT_EQ(0, 0) << pair1; //compiles
        EXPECT_EQ(0, 0) << pair2; //doesn't compile
    }
}
```

I use Visual Studio 2015. Error text is:

> Error C2679   binary '<<': no operator found which takes a right-hand
>   operand of type 'const std::pair' (or there is no acceptable
>   conversion)   ...\gtest\gtest-message.h 131

How changing user-defined type to built-in type makes a difference?

**Upd.** Thanks to @Kerrek SB, error is explained. However, now there is another question: How should I overload operator<< for `std::pair` to be able to use it like in my code?

Comment: Because name lookup does not look in namespace `A` to find your operator overload.

Comment: But it finds it for `pair<C,C>`. Why it only does not find it for `pair<int,int>`?

Comment: Because templates and ADL. `C` is in namespace `A`, so `A` is among the associated namespaces for that lookup.

Comment: Please create a MCVE (minimal, complete, and verifiable example). I suspect you can eliminate the dependence on the Google code and include a main function so that you have a compiling program demonstrating your problem.

Comment: @KerrekSB, Ok, I see now. So don't you know, where should I put my overload to compile this code?

Comment: @DmitryJ: You can't, really. The rule of thumb is that you can only customize things that involve at least one user-defined type. To make this work, you would have to add the operator to namespace `std`, which you're not allowed to.

Comment: @KerrekSB I was unable to reproduce the problem (making what I thought would be a trivial change to remove the Google Test dependence) -- could you comment if possible?

Comment: @jwimberley: Yeah, the OP seems to have shown the test code in the wrong namespace. I imagine the real situation is something like [this](https://wandbox.org/permlink/saLbX9zHqIxdkk0u).

Comment: @KerrekSB,  the code in the question is exactly like in my editor.  But error is coming from `::testing::Message::operator<<`, which, I suppose, is called inside `TEST` macro.

Answer (score 4):

When one writes something like `EXPECT_EQ(e1,e2) << some_pair`, the template function

```
template<typename T> 
::testing::Message::operator<<
```

is being instantiated. Only inside this function user-defined `operator<<` is being called. Because function resides in another namespace (not in `A`) user-defined `operator<<` can't be found.

Solution is easy. Gtest offers function `::testing::PrintToString` which accepts STL containers. So the code should be like this (I changed it to make sense):

```
EXPECT_TRUE(some_predicate(pair2)) << ::testing::PrintToString(pair2);
```

Comment: I think OP wanted to avoid anything similar to ```::testing::PrintToString``` in their program.

Answer (score 2):

You need to define `operator <<` for `std::pair` in `std` namespace for `gtest` to find it.

The code as follows compiles fine:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "gtest/gtest.h"
#include <utility>

namespace std
{

//overloading operator << for std::pair
template<typename T1, typename T2>
ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const pair<T1, T2>& p) {
    return os << "pair:{" << p.first << ", " << p.second << "}";
}

}

namespace A {

    struct C {
        int x;
    };
    std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const C& c) {
        return os << c.x;
    }

    TEST(TestA, testA) {
        std::pair<C, C> pair1;
        std::pair<int, int> pair2;

        EXPECT_EQ(0, 0) << pair1; //compiles
        EXPECT_EQ(0, 0) << pair2; //compiles!
    }
}
```

Comment: Not allowed; see [Extending the namespace `std`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/extending_std).

Answer (score 0):

I took your answer and turned it into a minimal example, removing the dependence on the Google code:

```
#include <iostream>

namespace A {

    template<typename T1, typename T2>
    std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const std::pair<T1, T2>& p) {
        return os << "pair:{" << p.first << ", " << p.second << "}";
    }

    struct C {
        int x;
    };
    std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const C& c) {
        return os << c.x;
    }

    void test() {
        std::pair<C, C> pair1;
        std::pair<int, int> pair2;

        std::cout << pair1 << std::endl; // compiles
        std::cout << pair2 << std::endl; // also compiles
    }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    A::test();
}
```

This actually compiles fine for me, with the output

```
pair:{0, 0}
pair:{0, 0}
```

So, I cannot reproduce your problem. However, @KerrekSB has identified a good reason for your problem. I suspect the difference might lie in the fact that your code calls `operator<<` inside TEST, some type of macro defined by the Google Test package, while my more minimal example replaces this with a function in the namespace `A`, perhaps changing the name lookup?

Comment: Your code is not equivalent to the original ```gtest``` program, because you call ```operator <<``` for ```std::cout```, and in the original program this operator is called for ```gtest::interal::message``` object. So the problem with namespace arises.